# aws sdk api updateFunctionConfiguration - Rate exceeded

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

Issue:

Invoking this aws api for around 60 lambda functions saying  'Rate exceed'

```
const myLambda = new AWS.Lambda();
  
  myLambda.updateFunctionConfiguration({
      FunctionName:'function-name-%{i}',
      Environment: { Variables: myVariables },
    })
```

Any clue

Answer (score 0):

To solve this: below are the options:

- Raise a support ticket to AWS help & ask them to increase the quota
- Limit the no.of calls per second and send next batch with some delay.

I did both and it is improved.